# C# linq groupby with many to many table record

Tags: c#-4.0, linq-to-entities

I am trying to get the following result with the below shown data. I am not sure how to achieve the result using linq group by. Can anyone please help how to solve this? I am using EntityFramework to get entities.

```
public class Student
{
    public long StudentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<StudentCourse> Courses { get; set; }     
}

public class Course
{
    public long CourseId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<StudentCourse> Students { get; set; }
}

public class StudentCourse
{
    public virtual long StudentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }

    public virtual long CourseId { get; set; }
    public virtual Course Course { get; set; }

    public string Location { get; set; }
}
```

Sample Data:

```
Student
-------
StudentId   Name
8           Stud8

Course:
------
CourseId    Name
88          Course88
148         Course148
196         Course196
453         Course453

StudentCourse: (StudentId + CourseId + Location makes the uniqueness) 
------------
StudentId   CourseId    Location    
8           88          Location 88 
8           88          Location 89 
8           148         Location 148    
8           196         Location 196    
8           453         Location 453    

Expected Result for StudentId 8:

CourseId    Name        Location
--------    -----       -------
88          Course88    Location 88
88          Course88    Location 89
148         Course148   Location 148    
196         Course196   Location 196    
453         Course453   Location 453
```

As shown in the above example, courses can be repeated for different location.

How to get the above result using C# linq group by. I have tried the following:

```
    var courses = context.courses.Select(g => new
    {
        Course = g,
        Location = g.Students.FirstOrDefault(m => m.StudentId == studentId).Location,
    });

    but i am not getting the right course for the same recipe.
```

The following code works for me. But like to know if there is a better way to do this. I am adding the added item to

```
    var existingStudentCourses = new List<Model.Entity.StudentCourse>();
    var result = new List<CustomClass>();
        foreach(var item in context.courses)
        {
            var studentCourses = item.Students.Where(x=>x.StudentId == studentId && !existingStudentCourses.Any(y=>y.Equals(x)));
            var studentCourse = studentCourses.FirstOrDefault();
            existingStudentCourses.Add(studentCourse);
            result.Add(new CustomClass
            {
                Course = item,
                Location = studentCourse.Location
            });
        }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

can you query the StudentCourses table? then the code will be

```
var StudentCourses =context.studentCourses.Where(c => c.StudentId == studentId).Select(c => new CustomClass
    {
        Course = c.Course ,
        Location = c.Location
    })
```

if you must use the course table you can try

```
var StudentCourses = context.courses.Where(c => c.Students.Any(s => s.StudentId == studentId)).Select(c => new CustomClass
    {
        Course = c,
        Location = context.studentCourse.FirstOrDefault(sc=>sc.StudentId==studentId && sc.CourseId==c.CourseId).Location
    }).Distinct()
```